# CAS and GWT - keeping GWT place on CAS redirect

Tags: gwt, cas, gwtp

I'm trying to use CAS as an SSO solution for my organization.
One of the application that use this solution is a GWT application, using GWTP as its MVP platform.

When trying to navigate to some internal place in my app, for example:

```
http://myapp.com/myapp.html#!somePlace
```

the CAS filter recognize I'm not authenticated, and I get redirected to to the CAS login page. This is expected.
But, as we know, the internal place state (#!somePlace) is not sent to the server so it is not kept in CAS redirect request. Therefore, after loggining-in in CAS, I'm simply redirected to:

```
http://myapp.com/myapp.html
```

So I cannot reproduce the internal place that was requested.

Does anyone have some experience with integrating CAS and GWT and solving or working-around this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's [pull request](https://github.com/Jasig/cas/pull/100/files) for your issue currently on GitHub.

Briefly, as far as the anchor part of the initial URL appends to the "service" parameter of the login page in CAS server application, the simplest solution will be to add "onsubmit" event handler to the form on the login page. In event handler function you should extract part after "#" in current location and you should then add that part to the value of form.action.